Open Telemetery and Dependency Missing On Application Map For Azure Function
I am trying to create an Azure Function with typescript. I am fairly new to both. I followed the docs and create one Azure function using the steps mentioned in the Azure Docs.
Docs: Azure function With Typecript
I am using programming model v4, host.json v2, Runtime worker: node, worker runtime version is ~4 and node version 20. I have trying to get my dependencies to appear in the application map but it's not showing for some reason.
I have integration with Azure Key Vault, Azure Flexible Server for Postgresql and ERP system. Function itself is working fine.
I enabled application insight in my host.json as follows:
"applicationInsights": {
  "samplingSettings": {
    "isEnabled": true,
    "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20,
    "excludedTypes": "Request;Exception"
  },
  "enableDependencyTracking": true,
  "enableLiveMetrics": true,
  "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
},

And enabled opentelmetery for custom telemetry as follows:
"telemetryMode": "OpenTelemetry",

Docs: host.json
When I don't use OpenTelemetery then only my function appear in the Application Map. When I use Opentelemetry then my function and opentelemetry service name both appear in the application map but not connected to each other.
I am instrumenting my OpenTelemetery as mentioned in Docs: Use OpenTelemetry With Azure Functions
This is how my instrumentation logic looks like and it is being executed before the function registers during invocation:
import { AzureFunctionsInstrumentation } from "@azure/functions-opentelemetry-instrumentation";
import {
  AzureMonitorLogExporter,
  AzureMonitorTraceExporter,
  AzureMonitorMetricExporter,
} from "@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter";
import {
  getNodeAutoInstrumentations,
  getResourceDetectors,
} from "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node";
import { registerInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation";
import { detectResourcesSync, Resource } from "@opentelemetry/resources";
import {
  LoggerProvider,
  SimpleLogRecordProcessor,
  BatchLogRecordProcessor,
} from "@opentelemetry/sdk-logs";
import {
  NodeTracerProvider,
  SimpleSpanProcessor,
  BatchSpanProcessor,
} from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node";
import {
  MeterProvider,
  PeriodicExportingMetricReader,
} from "@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics";

export async function initializeAzureMonitorInstrumentation() {
  // Detect resources with appropriate service name
  const resource = detectResourcesSync({
    detectors: getResourceDetectors(),
  }).merge(
    new Resource({
      "service.name": "TestService", // Directly setting the service name
    })
  );

  const isBatchExport = Number(process.env.OTEL_BATCH_EXPORT) === 1;

  // Initialize the TracerProvider with resources
  const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider({ resource });
  const tracerSpanProcessor = isBatchExport
    ? new BatchSpanProcessor(new AzureMonitorTraceExporter())
    : new SimpleSpanProcessor(new AzureMonitorTraceExporter());
  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(tracerSpanProcessor);
  tracerProvider.register();

  // LoggerProvider setup
  const loggerProvider = new LoggerProvider({ resource });
  const logRecordProcessor = isBatchExport
    ? new BatchLogRecordProcessor(new AzureMonitorLogExporter())
    : new SimpleLogRecordProcessor(new AzureMonitorLogExporter());
  loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(logRecordProcessor);

  // MeterProvider with periodic metric exporter
  const meterProvider = new MeterProvider({
    resource,
    readers: [
      new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
        exporter: new AzureMonitorMetricExporter(),
        exportIntervalMillis: 60000, // Every 60 seconds
      }),
    ],
  });

  // Register all instrumentations
  registerInstrumentations({
    tracerProvider,
    loggerProvider,
    meterProvider,
    instrumentations: [
      getNodeAutoInstrumentations(),
      new AzureFunctionsInstrumentation(),
    ],
  });
}

I have been through many docs, but I can't seem to make it work. Probably because I am using model v4.Here is the list of few links that I browsed.
DOCS: Configure Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry
DOCS: Monitor your Node.js services and apps with Application Insights
DOCS: Application map: Triage distributed applications
GITHUB: ApplicationInsights-node.js
I have so many questions like:

When Application Insight is enabled, then what we log using InvocationContext object goes to application insight. Do I have to keep passing this context object throughout my code? Is there no other way?
What if I am to use custom telemetry, how do I create custom telemetry and how do I make it show in the Application Insight?
Why my dependencies are not appearing in the Application Map?
Am I doing something wrong, i followed the docs though.

I would really appreciate any kind of help with questions.
This is how my application map looks like:

This is how my application map looks like after enabling openTelemtery:

All red lines are call to metadata.google.internal.:80/computeMetadata/v1/instance
I don't know what's making that call, still trying to figure that out.
I don't see my postgres and key vault connection either, i am not even sure if that should appear here or not.

Can you share your folder structure?

What can you see in Application Map? Please share a screenshot

I can see the Map in this way

Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, I have added image in my question.  My directory structure is bit different. I am using inversify to resolve the classes and interfaces. The image I shared is without adding Open Telemetry instrumentation. When I add the open telemetery instrumentation I have two node one which is in the image and second node with custom opentelemetry. However none of it shows any dependency.

Can you share the screenshot of Map by using Open telemetry? Also check my screenshot, I have added for your reference

I only have Http Dependency which I can see in Map @RishabhDwivedi

Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, sorry for late reply. Work has been crazy. I can also see the dependencies but I have what those dependencies are one dependency is trying to call google.metadata.com but no dependency like DB connection and Key Vault are not appearing. I am fairly new to this so I don't even know how it works. I could have shared the screenshot but I removed OpenTelemetry from my function for now. Could you please share your code with me? I will compare it to mine and check if I am doing the same thing.

Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, I added my application map with open telemetry and updated it in my question.

Have you tried my code?

Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, I am doing pretty much the same thing.

I have used key vault in my code but I am not getting any node named metadata, I believe it might be coming from postgres database. Is it possible to check once using key vault

Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, I am fetching the db connection string from key vault itself.

Try to check in application insight to more about this call, as I am getting these and map. If you are doing everything correctly then you should get this too. I would suggest you to perform the whole steps from the scratch once again @RishabhDwivedi

Hi @NaveenSharma, it hasn't solved the problem.  I posted list of list of questions, whatever is in the solution I already had that in place. I am still trying to figure out the problem, just hasn't gotten the time to debug it yet.

I am using the given code to add key vault dependency in Application Map.
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
import { SecretClient } from "@azure/keyvault-secrets";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const keyVaultUrl = "https://afreeenkvv.vault.azure.net";

const secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, credential);

export async function httpTrigger(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
  context.log(`Http function processed request for URL "${request.url}"`);

  try {
    const secretName = "mySecret"; 
    const secret = await secretClient.getSecret(secretName);

    return {
      status: 200,
      body: `Retrieved secret value: ${secret.value}`,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    context.log(`Error retrieving secret: ${err.message}`);

    return {
      status: 500,
      body: "Error retrieving secret from Key Vault",
    };
  }
}

app.http('httpTrigger', {
  methods: ['GET'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  handler: httpTrigger
});

telemetry.ts-
import { detectResourcesSync, Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import { NodeTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node';
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import { AzureMonitorTraceExporter } from '@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter';
import { SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base';

export async function initializeAzureMonitorInstrumentation() {
  const resource = detectResourcesSync().merge(
    new Resource({
      'service.name': 'MyAzureFunctionApp'
    })
  );

  const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider({ resource });

  const traceExporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter();
  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(traceExporter));

  tracerProvider.register();

  registerInstrumentations({
    tracerProvider,
    instrumentations: [
      getNodeAutoInstrumentations()
    ],
  });
}

index.ts-
import { app } from '@azure/functions';
import { initializeAzureMonitorInstrumentation } from './telemetry';

initializeAzureMonitorInstrumentation()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Azure Monitor instrumentation initialized successfully');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Failed to initialize Azure Monitor instrumentation:', err);
  });

app.setup({
    enableHttpStream: true,
});

host.json-
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableDependencyTracking": true,
      "enableLiveMetrics": true
    }
  },
  "telemetryMode": "OpenTelemetry",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

For local development, I have added Application Insight connection string in local settings file.
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=7bb*****63f7;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus2-3.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus2.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=2de*****720"
  }
}

I have got the expected response in application map post invoking the function.

